# Firebase Auth Logout and Tokens

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When I logout a user using `signOut`, the tokens still appear valid when I do `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)`. I understand I can check if token is revoked using `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token, true)` but I will need to revoke all refreshTokens for the user, which is not ideal? Anyway I can support logout on that device? Like logout on 1 refreshToken only.

Comment: What did you end up doing about this? Did you revoke the tokens or just let them expire (since they have a 1hr limit)?